# Display page name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

How would I add `location.href.split('/').pop()` to a html document to display the page name? (not the whole URL) I would like to display the page name ONLY.

example:
if the page was "www.example.com/whaterver/mypage.html"
it would display "mypage".

What would be the full script? I am new to javascript and I found this online but I don't know the whole code. could anyone help me out?

Comment: *I found this online*. If you are new to Javascript you should be asking how that code works instead of how to build on it. That way you can write it yourself next time

Comment: well I practically code no javascript but I wanted a script I could add to the header of my site that will display the page name over multiple documents.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick it in a function in case you need to reuse it elsewhere in your code. Just split the page name at the end and take the first element:

```
function getPageName(url) {
  return url.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
}
```

You can pass in the actual URL:

```
var pageName = getPageName('www.example.com/whaterver/mypage.html'); // mypage
```

Or, using `location.href`:

```
var pageName = getPageName(location.href); // mypage
```

I might also be inclined to return something if there is no match for `*.html`, so here's a revised function that returns null if there isn't a match:

```
function getPageName(url) {
  var pageName = url.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
  return pageName.length > 0 ? pageName : null;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ydq1549a/)

Comment: Exactly what I would have posted. Micro-optimization: `location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** If you do `.split('.')` like other solutions instruct, you will miss the base names from many URLs.

---

You can find the last forward slash and search ahead for the first `.`, `?`,  `&` or `#` to catch variations of URLs. This is the equivalent of PHP's [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
function getBaseName(url) {
  if(!url || (url && url.length === 0)) {
    return "";
  }
  var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
  var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
  var basename = filenameWithExtension.split(/[.?&#]+/)[0];

  // Handle '/mypage/' type paths
  if(basename.length === 0) {
    url = url.substr(0,index-1);
    basename = getBaseName(url);
  }
  return basename ? basename : ""; 
}
```

and use it like so

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage.html";
var file = getBaseName(url);
```

of

```
var file = getBaseName(location.pathname); // The current script page
```

---

**Results:**

```
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage/        =>  "mypage"
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage.html    =>  "mypage"  
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage         =>  "mypage"  
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage/        =>  "mypage"  
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage#works   =>  "mypage"  
http://www.example.com/whaterver/mypage?ver=1   =>  "mypage"
```

### [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/xinunenafe/1/watch?js,console)